# Generating an HTML message for jQuery dialog from two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays - `array1` and `array2` as shown in the code snippet below. I want to store following information in a message variable such that I could use that in a jQuery dialog.

So, in case of following arrays, I want have my message variable hold following information:

```
1 . File ABC012345 is located inside BOX#9

2.  File DEF06789 is located inside BOX#10
```

```js
var array1 = [
  "ABC012345",
  "DEF06789"
]

var array2 = [
  "BOX#9",
  "BOX#10"
]



let messageOne = "1.File "+array1[0]+" is located inside "+array2[0];

let messageTwo = "2.File "+array1[1]+" is located inside "+array2[1];

//console.log(messageOne);

//console.log(messageTwo);

for (i = 0 ; i < array1.length; i++){

   for (j = 0 ; j < array2.length ; j ++) {
   
   let message = "File "+array1[i]+" is located inside "+array2[j];
   console.log(message);
   
   }


}
```

But the way I'm attempting to do is producing incorrect results. Is there a better / correct way of approachin it?

Comment: Why are you using nested loops?

Comment: So what approach I should follow here?

Comment: A single loop: `for( let i = 0; i < Math.min( array1.length, array2.length ); i++ ) console.log( \`File ${array1[i]} is located inside ${array2[i]}\` );`

Comment: @Dai Thanks. Why `Math.min( array1.length, array2.length )` is needed?

Comment: Just in case the arrays have a different length.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to nested loop for this case, you can do it in just 1 loop

```
  for (i = 0 ; i < array1.length; i++){
       let message = "File "+array1[i]+" is located inside "+array2[i];
       console.log(message);
  }
```